# Connecting Firebase DB to Next.js app error

Tags: database, firebase, next.js

I'm trying to connect my NextJS app to get data from my Firebase database. I'm basing my implementation off of this example: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-nodejs/tree/master/database

Here's what I have so far:

in lib/firebase.js

```
import firebase from "firebase-admin";
const serviceAccount = require("../serviceAccount.json");

firebase.initializeApp(
  {
    credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://myDB.firebaseio.com",
  },
  "DB"
);

export default firebase;
```

and then in pages/index.js

```
import firebase from "../lib/firebase";

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  var test = firebase.database().ref("artsci");
  test.on("value", function (snapshot) {
    return {
      props: { test }, // will be passed to the page component as props
    };
  });
}
```

However whenever I run `yarn dev` I get this error:

Error: Firebase app named "DB" already exists. This means you called initializeApp() more than once with the same app name as the second argument. Make sure you provide a unique name every time you call initializeApp().

Also if I add this line to my firebase.js

```
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(
    {
      credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
      databaseURL: "https://myDB.firebaseio.com",
    },
    "DB"
  );
}
```

Then I get this error:

Error: The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services.

Any tips or resources would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I came up with the following code when I got into the same problem. Check it out:-

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/storage';
import 'firebase/firestore';

export const connectFB = () => {
    const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: process.env.apiKey,
        authDomain: process.env.authDomain,
        databaseURL: process.env.databaseURL,
        projectId: process.env.projectId,
        storageBucket: process.env.storageBucket,
        messagingSenderId: process.env.messagingSenderId,
        appId: process.env.appId
    };

    if (!firebase.apps.length) {
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    }

    return firebase;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `.env` file to store all the credentials and directly using it to fetch during runtime is actually much hassle free.

Try this way https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/14420#discussioncomment-29816